# How to use two Viewholders in a single adapter

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapterview

I am facing an issue while using sectioning in a listview . I need to use viewholder to make  listview scroll smooth but I don't know how to implement  two viewholders as ther are two seperate views one is section and second is simple entry .Here is the code what I have tried and the error I got .Please tell me where I am doing wrong and how can I correct it :

**CODE**

```
@
Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final GroupAccountdto i = items.get(position);
    if (i != null) {
        if (i.isSection()) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_group_section, null);
                ViewHolderGroup group_holder = new ViewHolderGroup();
                group_holder.group_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_section_group_name);
                convertView.setTag(group_holder);
            }
            ViewHolderGroup group_holder = (ViewHolderGroup) convertView.getTag();
            GiddhGroups si = (GiddhGroups) i;
            group_holder.group_name.setText(si.getGroupname());

        } else {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_account, null);
                ViewHolderAccount account_holder = new ViewHolderAccount();
                account_holder.account_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_account_name);
                account_holder.account_bal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_account_balance);
            }
            ViewHolderAccount account_holder = (ViewHolderAccount) convertView.getTag();
            GiddhAccounts ei = (GiddhAccounts) i;

            if (account_holder.account_name != null)
                account_holder.account_name.setText(ei.getAccountName());
            if (account_holder.account_bal != null)
                account_holder.account_bal.setText(ei.getBalance());
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolderGroup {
    TextView group_name;
}

static class ViewHolderAccount {
    public TextView account_name;
    public TextView account_bal;
}
```

**ERROR**

```
02-27 12:49:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(20200): java.lang.ClassCastException: adapters.GroupAccountAdapter$ViewHolderGroup cannot be cast to adapters.GroupAccountAdapter$ViewHolderAccount
02-27 12:49:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(20200):    at adapters.GroupAccountAdapter.getView(GroupAccountAdapter.java:53)
02-27 12:49:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(20200):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2334)
02-27 12:49:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(20200):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1409)
02-27 12:49:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(20200):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1273)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override `getItemViewType()` in your `ListAdapter`, returning a distinct number for each type of row. In your case, you could return `0` for sections and `1` for regular rows. Then, `getView()` will be called with the proper `View` type for recycling.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
  if (getItem(position).isSection()) {
    return(0);
  }

  return(1);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering .Do you have any sample of it ???As I am doing it first time looking bit complex